# Extract a substring after some string in C#

Tags: c#, substring

For example:

```
INPUT: sample="DA ---- Dear Allowance"
OUTPUT: "Dear Allowance"
```

I want this type of scenario in  C#.

Comment: To answer this, I'd need to know which parts of the string will be like your example. In other words, what are the rules for finding the string.

Comment: try reading about IndexOf and SubString

Comment: Check this: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+substring I know, it is just a google link, but posting all good pages about substrings would be a bit heavy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all your strings have the same format like `Code ---- FullName`
you can do it simple-

```
   string sName = "DA ---- Dear Allowance".Split(new string[]{"----"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim();
```

Comment: or `text.Split(new[] { " ---- " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim()` which doesn't throw an exception if there is no delimiter.

Comment: @TimSchmelter; you are right; That is why I have mentioned in the answer- **If all string having the same format**

Comment: @Rohit: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Its showing this error

Comment: @RohitPrakash: i'd prefer an approach which works even if they hadn't the same format. Otherwise you should have mentioned the error that happens if it doesn't contain the delimiter and check the `string[]`-length to prevent against it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: by doing "text.Split(new[] { " ---- " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim()"....I am getting DA but not Dear Allowance